# function with bounded 1st and 2nd derivative

Tags: calculus

I just have a simple question about what it means when a function's 1st and 2nd derivatives are bounded.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying the first derivative is bounded means there is an $M>0$ such that $|f'(x)|<M$ for all $x$ in the domain of the function. Likewise for the second derivative $f''(x)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Okay, so it means for the 1st derivative the change is bounded by M...However, what does it mean for the 2nd derivative. I thought second derivatives where just used for knowing if a function is positive or negative.

Comment: @user3282435 As you walk along the graph of $f$, the second derivative measures how fast you "turn", i.e. how much the graph curves. So if the second derivative is bounded, it means you never turn faster than that bound.

Comment: Great!! Thank you very much Arthur and Jasper!!